# C++ overloaded new issue

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have made a small mechanism that replaces the regular new operator.
Basically we allocate a pool of memory (like 16mb) and when new is called, return
an offset to it that grows until there is no more room and we make another pool. A pool
is deleted only when all of the elements in that pool are freed.

I have tested this class and it works great and around 8-15 times faster than the original new.
There is a problem however: I incorporated it into my other project which is huge in size, it 
works normally except the memory usage grows very quickly. Basically the pools aren't freed because
some items in them are not deleted at all. Also, there are many calls to new(0) from STL containers
to which I dont know how should it respond.

Here is the code:

```
namespace rt
{
      class pool
      {
            friend class alloc;
            private:
                    unsigned int _numRecords;
                    unsigned int _sizeLeft;
                    char*        _ptr;
                    char*        _data;


      };


      class alloc
      {
            public:
                   alloc();

                   alloc(int mb);

                   ~alloc();

                   void* allocate(unsigned int size);

                   void constructPool(unsigned int idx);

                   void destroyPool(unsigned int idx);

                   void deallocate(void* ptr);

            private:
                    const static unsigned int           _numPools = 256;
                    const static unsigned int           _poolSize = 15*1024*1024;
                    const static unsigned int           _poolReplaceBound = 1*1024*1024; // if 1mb or less left we can replace it
                    pool*                               _pools[_numPools];
                    unsigned int                        _curPoolIdx;


      };
```

That was the header.
Here is the implementation:

```
namespace rt
{
          class pool
          {
                friend class alloc;
                private:
                        unsigned int _numRecords;
                        unsigned int _sizeLeft;
                        char*        _ptr;
                        char*        _data;

          };


      class alloc
      {
            public:
                   alloc();

                   alloc(int mb);

                   ~alloc();

                   void* allocate(unsigned int size);

                   void constructPool(unsigned int idx);

                   void destroyPool(unsigned int idx);

                   void deallocate(void* ptr);

            private:
                    const static unsigned int           _numPools = 256;
                    const static unsigned int           _poolSize = 15*1024*1024;
                    const static unsigned int           _poolReplaceBound = 1*1024*1024; // if 1mb or less left we can replace it
                    pool*                               _pools[_numPools];
                    unsigned int                        _curPoolIdx;


      };          

      extern alloc default_allocator;
}


#define RT_SAFE_MEM
namespace rt
{
      alloc default_allocator;


      alloc::alloc() 
      {
                     for(int i = 0; i < _numPools; i++) _pools[i] = NULL;
                     _curPoolIdx = 0;
                     constructPool(_curPoolIdx);
      }

      alloc::~alloc()
      {

      }

      void alloc::constructPool(unsigned int idx)
      {
                                    _pools[idx] = (pool*)malloc(sizeof(pool));
                                    _pools[idx]->_numRecords = 0;
                                    _pools[idx]->_sizeLeft = _poolSize;
                                    _pools[idx]->_data = (char*)calloc(_poolSize, 1);

                                    _pools[idx]->_ptr = _pools[idx]->_data; 
      }

      void alloc::destroyPool(unsigned int idx)
      {
           free(_pools[idx]->_data);
           free(_pools[idx]);
           _pools[idx] = NULL;
      }

      void* alloc::allocate(unsigned int size)
      {
            if(size == 0)
            {
                    return NULL;
            }
            #ifdef RT_SAFE_MEM

                                  if(size > _poolSize) 
                                  {
                                          MessageBox(NULL, "Allocation size exceeded maximum.", "Executor", MB_OK);
                                          return NULL;
                                  }
                                  if(*(_pools[_curPoolIdx]->_ptr) != 0)
                                  {
                                                                  //leak
                                                                  unsigned int leaksize = strlen(_pools[_curPoolIdx]->_ptr);
                                                                  char str[50];
                                                                  sprintf(str, "Memory corruption detected: wrote extra %u bytes. \nExporting to corrupt.txt", leaksize);
                                                                  FILE* fp = fopen("corrupt.txt", "w");
                                                                  fwrite(_pools[_curPoolIdx]->_ptr, 1, leaksize, fp);
                                                                  fclose(fp);
                                                                  MessageBox(NULL, str, "Executor", MB_OK);
                                                                  return NULL;
                                  }

            #endif

            if(_pools[_curPoolIdx]->_sizeLeft <= size)
            {
                                              //not enough size in this pool
                                              //make a new one
                                              _curPoolIdx++;
                                              //printf("expand");
                                              constructPool(_curPoolIdx);
                                              return allocate(size);

            }
            else
            {
                void* ans = (void*)_pools[_curPoolIdx]->_ptr;
                _pools[_curPoolIdx]->_ptr+=size;
                _pools[_curPoolIdx]->_sizeLeft-=size;
                _pools[_curPoolIdx]->_numRecords++;
                return ans;
            }
      }


      void alloc::deallocate(void* ptr)
      {
           for(int i = 0; i <= _curPoolIdx; i++)
           {
                   if(ptr >= _pools[i]->_data && ptr < _pools[i]->_ptr)
                   { 
                          //pool i contains this object
                          //printf("found %d\n", i); 
                          _pools[i]->_numRecords--;
                          if(_pools[i]->_numRecords == 0 && _pools[i]->_sizeLeft <= _poolReplaceBound)
                          {
                                                    //replace this pool
                                                    printf("replacing %d\n", i);
                                                    destroyPool(i);
                                                    if(_curPoolIdx == 0) constructPool(0);
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        for(int j = i; j < _numPools-1; j++)
                                                        {
                                                                _pools[j] = _pools[j+1];
                                                        } 
                                                        _curPoolIdx--;
                                                    }

                          }
                          return;
                   }
           }
           #ifdef RT_SAFE_MEM
                  char str[50];
                  sprintf(str,  "Attempted to deallocate foreign memory at 0x%.8X.", ptr);
                  MessageBox(NULL, str, "Executor", MB_OK);
           #endif
      }
```

}

If anyone sees a bug or a major problem, let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: What's with the crazy indentation?

Comment: To answer one part of your question. If you get a request for zero bytes you should not return NULL. Treat all requests for zero bytes as a request for one byte and you won't go wrong.

Comment: What's with the gratuitous prefix "_"?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do **all** the below steps:

1. Write a test program to test that your program runs bug-free or "has any problems"
2. use a debugger to find bugs, not the SO's audience :-P
3. Instead of posting a full listing of your code you should write-up what your code does - this will serve you as a **great** reference point in future and also will be a useful documentation for what (and how) your code does